# Copy data activity fails when sink is immutable

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

In my Azure data factory pipeline, I'm using a Copy data activity inside a ForEach activity to copy files from an input container to an archive container before processing the files in the input container. This normally works, but today I made the archive container immutable by adding a legal hold policy to it, and the next time the copy data activity ran, it failed with an error (see below). Is there any way around this, since you should be able to add new files to an immutable container?

Error code: 2200
Failure type: User configuration issue
Details:
Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=AdlsGen2OperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ADLS Gen2 operation failed for: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Conflict'. Account: 'mydatalake'. FileSystem: 'raw'. Path: 'Source/ABC/File_2021_03_24.csv'. ErrorCode: 'PathImmutableDueToLegalHold'. Message: 'This operation is not permitted as the path is immutable due to one or more legal holds.'. RequestId: '37f75e88-501a-0026-2fa1-20d52e000000'. TimeStamp: 'Wed, 24 Mar 2021 11:30:54 GMT'..,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.Models.ErrorSchemaException,Message=Operation returned an invalid status code 'Conflict',Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'
Source: Pipeline LoadMyData

Comment: After the failure, what is in the container? Is there any chance the same blob name was processed twice? That would register as a delete operation. It's also possible that ADF wrote the blob with a staging name and then tried to rename it accordingly, which would probably register as a modification. It would probably leave behind a blob with a GUID or otherwise odd name.

Comment: Now, I'm running a test pipeline with only file to copy, and after the failure, there is an empty file in the sink container with the same name as the non-empty file in the source container.

Comment: It sounds like Copy may be creating a Lease on the name with an empty file and then failing trying to overwrite the Lease. Or the blob is created as an empty Append Blob that they attempt to append during the process, which is failing. In either case, that would cause the problem you are seeing. I would suggest putting in a support ticket with the ADF team.

Comment: I submitted a support ticket to Microsoft about it, and they confirmed it's a bug that they are working on fixing. Thanks for your input!